# Is it better to derive from Gtk.Widget or directly from a specific widget?

Tags: python, gtk

When I create a UI class for my app, I often wonder if it's better to derive my class from `Gtk.Widget` and then add explicitly the widgets I need or to derive directly from a specific widget.

Here is two examples, which one is the best?

```py
class MyComponent(Gtk.Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Widget.__init__(self)

        box = Gtk.Box.new(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 6)
        button1 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Awesome Button1")
        button2 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Awesome Button2")
        button3 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Awesome Button3")
        box.pack_start(button1, True, True, 0)
        box.pack_start(button2, True, True, 0)
        box.pack_start(button3, True, True, 0)

        self.add(box)
```

```py
class MyComponent(Gtk.Box):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Box.__init__(self, Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 6)

        button1 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Awesome Button1")
        button2 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Awesome Button2")
        button3 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Awesome Button3")
        self.pack_start(button1, True, True, 0)
        self.pack_start(button2, True, True, 0)
        self.pack_start(button3, True, True, 0)
```

It seems to me that the first version is better since my component isn't technically a `Gtk.Box`, it's a widget that is using a `Gtk.Box`, but it could as well use a `Gtk.Grid` or a `Gtk.DrawingArea`.

So it seems right on a design stand point, but maybe there's some technicalities that I don't see. What's your advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the abstraction in your mind. Ask yourself: is your component merely a customised *box* or something *more*?

Moreover, do you *actually* need inheritance here? Perhaps you can just do away with a free factory-function that creates a group of Gtk.Widgets to your liking.

Comment: Yet another possible solution! ;) In my case I think I'd prefer to derive from a Gtk.Widget since what will be inside will be a more complex widget that I'll reuse several times. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see why you think the first is better. Just Subclass what you actually want. A Gtk.Box *is* a Gtk.Widget so wherever you can use the latter you can use the former.

Comment: It's more about object oriented programming. Sometime it's better to do an aggregation than a derivation. Also I thought that maybe, under the hood, GTK+ was better with aggregation for some special reasons that I couldn't know ;)